# Jinja2 batching and combining 2 lists

Tags: python, list, loops, jinja2

I have 2 lists I'm passing to a Jinja template:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import jinja2
app_machine_list=[
  "abcapp01",
  "abcapp02",
  "abcapp03",
  "abcapp04",
  "abcapp05",
  "abcapp06",
  "abcapp07",
  "abcapp08",
  "abcapp09",
  "abcapp10",
  "abcapp11",
  "abcapp12",
  "abcapp13",
  "oabcapp14"
]

machine_url_list=[
  "scheme://host1.app.local",
  "scheme://host2.app.local",
  "scheme://host3.app.local",
  "scheme://host4.app.local",
  "scheme://host5.app.local",
  "scheme://host6.app.local"
]

# Load template from file
template = jinja2.Template(open('template.j2').read())
print(template.render(app_machine_list=app_machine_list, machine_url_list=machine_url_list))
```

The first list I have divided into 3 clusters of 3, 3 and 6 app_machines.  The template for that looks like this:

```
{% for machine_batch in app_machine_list | batch((app_machine_list | length) // 3) -%}
  {% if loop.index == 1 %}
CLUSTER1
  {%- elif loop.index == 2 %}
CLUSTER2
  {%- elif loop.index == 3 %}
CLUSTER3
  {%- endif %}
  {%- for machine in machine_batch %}
  {{ machine }}
  {%- endfor %}
{%- endfor %}
```

Output for this is:

```
CLUSTER1
  abcapp01
  abcapp02
  abcapp03
  abcapp04
CLUSTER2
  abcapp05
  abcapp06
  abcapp07
  abcapp08
CLUSTER3
  abcapp09
  abcapp10
  abcapp11
  abcapp12
  abcapp13
  abcapp14
```

I want to be able to allocate 2 machine URLs to each cluster such that the output is like this:

```
CLUSTER1
  abcapp01 - scheme://host1.app.local
  abcapp02 - scheme://host1.app.local
  abcapp03 - scheme://host2.app.local
  abcapp04 - scheme://host2.app.local
CLUSTER2
  abcapp05 - scheme://host3.app.local
  abcapp06 - scheme://host3.app.local
  abcapp07 - scheme://host4.app.local
  abcapp08 - scheme://host4.app.local
CLUSTER3
  abcapp09 - scheme://host5.app.local
  abcapp10 - scheme://host5.app.local
  abcapp11 - scheme://host5.app.local
  abcapp12 - scheme://host6.app.local
  abcapp13 - scheme://host6.app.local
  abcapp14 - scheme://host6.app.local
```

I'm a novice at both Python and Jinja2, and I just can't figure out how to do this!  Any help really welcome.

Comment: Hi Сергей-Кох, I've updated it with the full code now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to implement a helper class like this in your Python code:

```
class Pairs:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items
        items_iter = iter(items)
        self.pairs = zip(items_iter, items_iter)
        self.next()

    def next(self):
        self.current = itertools.cycle(next(self.pairs))

    def cycle(self):
        return next(self.current)
```

And then call your template like:

```
template.render(
  app_machine_list=app_machine_list,
  urlpairs=Pairs(machine_url_list),
)
```

And then in your template:

```
{% for machine_batch in app_machine_list | batch((app_machine_list | length) // 3) -%}
  {%- if loop.index == 1 -%}
CLUSTER1
  {%- elif loop.index == 2 %}
CLUSTER2
  {%- set _ = urlpairs.next() %}
  {%- elif loop.index == 3 %}
CLUSTER3
  {%- set _ = urlpairs.next() %}
  {%- endif %}
  {%- for machine in machine_batch %}
  {{ machine }} - {{ urlpairs.cycle() }}
  {%- endfor %}
{%- endfor %}
```

Given your example data, that produces as output:

```
CLUSTER1
  abcapp01 - scheme://host1.app.local
  abcapp02 - scheme://host2.app.local
  abcapp03 - scheme://host1.app.local
  abcapp04 - scheme://host2.app.local
CLUSTER2
  abcapp05 - scheme://host3.app.local
  abcapp06 - scheme://host4.app.local
  abcapp07 - scheme://host3.app.local
  abcapp08 - scheme://host4.app.local
CLUSTER3
  abcapp09 - scheme://host5.app.local
  abcapp10 - scheme://host6.app.local
  abcapp11 - scheme://host5.app.local
  abcapp12 - scheme://host6.app.local
  abcapp13 - scheme://host5.app.local
  oabcapp14 - scheme://host6.app.local
```

You'll note that here the two hosts assigned to each cluster alternate, because that was much simpler than assigning one to the first half of the hosts and the second to the latter half (because doing so would require knowing the number of hosts in the group).

We're using the `{% set ... %}` calls in the template only for their side effects, so we assign to `_` to indicate that the return value is discarded.

---

While this works, it's a bit of a hack. If I were doing this from scratch, I would probably move all the logic into the Python code and simplify the template.